# Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: macos, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have setup an amazon EC2 intance using the command line tools. I have create a key pair for it etc. and it is up and running. I try to SSH into it using the following (I am running bash in Snow Leopard):

```
$ ssh -i ec2-keypair root@ec2-xxx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Snow Leopard pops up a box saying "Enter you password for the SSH key "ec2-keypair" ". Can someone please tell me what I should do? If I don't provide a password its just asks me for one in the bash terminal.

Thanks for the response. I create a key pair for Amazon EC2 using:

```
ec2-add-keypair ec2-keypair
```

I have create a password protected sash key and now have two files in my .ssh directory:

```
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
```

Do I need to transfer one of these to my EC2 instance? Which one? What is the best way of doing this and where shall I put?

Max.

Any help greatly appreciated as I have spent some while trying to sort this out.

Max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the key pair its best to pipe the output straight into a file so that there are no formatting issues, using:

ec2-add-keypair ec2-keypair | sed '1d' > ec2-keypair

Max.

Answer (score 3):

As you accepted Max's answer already maybe you're OK now, but you can get that error if the permissions on your keypair file are too permissive.  chmod it to 600 (owner read/write, group and all no permisions) and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly when you set up your ssh keys you are prompted to type a passphrase twice.  Most of the time you can just press enter twice, leaving the pass phrase blank.

Have you tried just submitting a blank passphrase?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I create a key pair for Amazon EC2 using:

ec2-add-keypair ec2-keypair

I have create a password protected sash key and now have two files in my .sash directory:
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub

Do I need to transfer one of these to my EC2 instance? Which one? What is the best way of doing this and where shall I put?

Max.

Comment: Typically the .pub key goes in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote machine.

If you are running some flavor of linux/unix locally then you might look into "ssh-copy-id" to make the process easier.

Or you can use "scp" to move the public key to the remote machine's authorized hosts location.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're using snow leopard, so basically free bsd, so ssh-copy-id should prbbly work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is just asking for the password you supplied when you created the key pair. If you didn't supply one then just enter nothing and click OK, otherwise enter the password to continue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I create a key pair for Amazon EC2 using:

ec2-add-keypair ec2-keypair

I have create a password protected sash key and now have two files in my .sash directory:
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub

Do I need to transfer one of these to my EC2 instance? Which one? What is the best way of doing this and where shall I put?

Max.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running an Ubuntu image you'll want to use the user 'ubuntu' instead of root for the micro instances. I'm not sure about other ones but for micro you do.

so at the prompt it would look like

```
$ ssh -i ec2-keypair ubuntu@ec2-xxx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The username should be ec2-user and not root. ssh Like this

```
$ ssh -i ec2-keypair ec2-user@ec2-xxx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```